# Flutter. Both Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding are specified, at most one is allowed

Tags: flutter, http

We have a problem with flutter application (SDK 2+).

We built an app which work with ESP via http (REST). It's IoT solution. Everything was ok. But then I upgrade flutter version and got this message when call one API method which return large dataset. We investigated this issue (we shouldn't send content-length and transfer-encoding both) and fixed it in new version of firmware (ESP side). But we have a lot of devices with old version of firmware in different locations without internet access.

May be you know way to loosen the restriction about this constraint in flutter?